# How to write joint venture company in Resume?

Tags: software-industry, resume

As I am in process of joint venture of my current company and soon, I will join new entity of 2 companies joint venture, how to write the new entity in my Resume?

Is it good to write something like this?

```
Company C - Joint venture of company A and B
```

Comment: Does it really matter who are the stakeholders in Company-C ? If  you are already employed by either company-A or company-B, and as a result of this joint venture, your title will change, then you might mention the reason for what looks like a job hopping, in the narrative part of employment with company-C

Comment: You are very correct. However, I don't want to be labeled as `job hopper`, that may make other companies afraid to even have an interview with me.

Comment: Then work the verbiage in to your job description in Company-C. Any reputable employer will understand, such thing are out of the control of eternal, little people in the trenches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you updating your resume right now?

You're concerned about being seen as a job-hopper, but no matter how you explain the relationships of A, B and C, I would read the resume as 'He's abandoning ship because one of those companies is a great big iceberg...'

If your role doesn't change, you only need to state the company name and something like 'merged Aug 2016' or similar - don't make a big deal out of it, unless you're a director and it really *is* a big deal.

Comment: I am agree with this. However, actually why I want to state it because it's kind of related with my other post here http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/72531/how-far-to-explain-my-resignation-reason-because-of-too-many-people-have-resigne

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you say which company employed you, then mention that you were working on a joint venture (if that's  relevant) in the description of the work.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply say that you are employed by Company C, which is in the process of merging with Companies A and B.

It will be important for you to clarify to what extent this merger is prompting you to seek new employment at this time. For example, is your position being eliminated, and/or are you credibly concerned that it might be? What do you anticipate that your job-description will be, post-merger? How is this affecting your decision to seek employment now?

It is also important for you to clarify whether you are the owner or an officer in any of the companies in question. Because, if you *are,* merger agreements ordinarily require present officers to remain in the employ of the merged companies at least for some period of time. I wouldn't want to waste my time hiring you, only to find out after-the-fact that you are contractually barred from taking the job.